# docker-compose run <container> with startup script

Tags: docker

How do I run `docker-compose run <container_image>` and have that put me into the container and then automatically run a startup or init script?

My Dockerfile I have my entrypoint as `["/bin/bash"]` which works.

When I add the command line to my compose file:

`command: /usr/local/bin/init.sh`

and run the compose, it just exits and doesn't provide me an interactive shell.

I'm sure this is trivial, but I can't figure it out, especially after exhaustive searching and trial & error.

Comment: There's not really a way to do that. You can (a) get a shell inside the container and run the script yourself, or (b) you can run a script from the command *instead* of getting an interactive shell.  It's the same behavior you would get running `bash` from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I ended up creating a `.bashrc` file in my docker file and adding the script in that file to be run at container startup.